# Java Simple Bit Manipulation Unexpected output

Tags: java, bit

```
        int x = 58;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 8) {
            int b = ((x >> 1) & 1);
            System.out.print(b);
            x = x >> 1;
            i++;

        }
```

The output is `10111000`
Since Last 8 bits of 58 should be: `00111010`
Should'nt output be `01011100` ??

I know I am missing something obvious, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are shifting the first bit before reading it, hence the result.  Change to:

```
int b = x&1;
```

and leave the rest of the code alone.

Comment: The answer you would be getting is the reverse.

Comment: That's true, but reversed was the OP's expected result

Answer (score 1):

You already start shifting before you output anything.

```
    int x = 58;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 8) {
        int b = (x & 1);
        System.out.print(b);
        x = x >> 1;
        i++;

    }
```

should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You get binary representation of `x` in reverse order and without first bit. You should write `int b = x & 1;` instead of `int b = ((x >> 1) & 1);` and store bits in array, and then output stored bits in a reverse order. Or just simple use `Integer.toString(x, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

58 = 111010

```
01110(1) & 1 = 1
00111(0) & 1 = 0
00011(1) & 1 = 1
00001(1) & 1 = 1
00000(1) & 1 = 1
00000(0) & 1 = 0
00000(0) & 1 = 0
00000(0) & 1 = 0
```

which is exactly 10111000

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading the last 8 bits, as you skip the last bit due to this line:

```
  int b = ((x >> 1) & 1);
```

Should rather be:

```
  int b = x & 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace above code with it. And print the array in reverse.

```
int x = 58;

        int i = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[8];
        while (i < 8) {
            arr[i]=x&1;
            x = x >> 1;
            i++;
        }
```